# I'm using re.split() and trying to join the elements but it doesn't work. Why is it?

Tags: python, split, python-re

I have a problem and I can't find reason why.
I want to divide the string into 3 parts, and the condition is "integer+Letter+*(optional)"
it works well when the number is one digit, but it doesn't work when the number is two digits.

This is my code:

```
import re
dartResult = '10S*3T2D*'
dartresult = re.split('(\d)',dartResult)   
dartresult=[i for i in dartresult if i != ""]
score = []
for i in range(len(dartresult)):
    try:
        if int(dartresult[i]):
            score.append(["".join(dartresult[i:i+2])])
        elif int(dartresult[i]) and int(dartresult[i+1]):   #in case the number is two digits
            score.append(["".join(dartresult[i:i+3])])    
    except:
        pass
print(dartresult)
print(score)
```

and this is the result.

```
['1', '0', 'S*', '3', 'T', '2', 'D*']
[['10'], ['3T'], ['2D*']]
```

and it would be nice if you let me know if there's a better way to divide the strings according to the condition above.

Comment: `\d` only refers to a single character, is why it's only capturing one digit. Did you mean to do `\d+`, which will take as many consecutive digits as possible?

Comment: why does `S*` disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply define all the elements in your regex?

```
import re
dartResult = '10S*3T2D*'
out = re.findall(r'\d+\w\*?', dartResult)
```

output:

```
>>> out
['10S*', '3T', '2D*']
```

regex:

```
\d+     # one or more digits
\w      # one character (letters/digit/underscore), to restrict to letters use [a-zA-Z]
\*?     # optionally, one "*" character
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a + immediately after your \d to capture any consecutive characters that are numerals.